# chrome in headless mode with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to open chrome in headless mode with selenium? I tried

```
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("headless")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chromeOptions)
```

but this just returns an error

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source: (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way

```
chromeOptions.add_argument("headless")
```

try this

```
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
```

I am using these config in my project, so thought it would be helpful to you.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
```

Note that `driver_path` is basically the `chromedriver.exe`, if `ChromeDriverManager().install()` works for you better stick with that.

Comment: I also tired `chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")` but the error persists.

Comment: add this args as well `chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=1')` and see if that helps.

Comment: I read about this in another thread, but it didn't work with my specific case because I have a function which opens a webpage and takes a screenshot. If I use `chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=1')`, then it redirects me to a page of cloudfare saying `protection against DDOS attacks. Please wait up to 5 seconds.`. This will slow down my program.

Answer (score 0):

`headless` is not a correct command format. Chrome command line switch always starts with `--` that means it should be `--headless`

> --headless: Run in headless mode, i.e., without a UI or display server dependencies.

**Code**:

```
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chromeOptions)
```

Please refer the below page for all command line switches and their details,

**Reference**: *https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/*

Comment: I also tired `chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")` but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using undetected_chrome, i used the below code to do mine and it worked perfectly

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
```